# At which point does a cell switch its function?

Tags: replication

In a multi cellular organisms there are many cells of different functions. How / when does a cell change its function compared to its parent? 
Is it done by influence of other cells after its has been created?

Comment: Yes, as opposed to what? Cells respond to signals, both within themselves and from other cells/tissues/organs, to differentiate. Sometimes a parent cells differentiates, then divides, and other times a parent (stem) cell divides and one of its daughter cells differentiates. Since the mechanisms and reasons are as varied as there are types of cells, I'm voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: Ok so the cell changes after mitosis not during mitosis. There is no mechanism during mitosis to change the function of a cell. Its all done by influences after the cell has been created.

Comment: That is not necessarily the case, as although it's rather unlikely that differentiation would begin during mitosis, there's no rule that says it can't. Like I said, this is a very broad question, as each differentiation event is slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MattDMo suggested there are so much possibilities. I would recommend to take a look at this information:

- [Cellular differentiation wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_differentiation)
- [The Cell: A Molecular Approach. 2nd edition (NCBI)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9918/)

I will summarize some points, however note that this will not include every aspect.
Every cell contains the same genome (same DNA), so what can make these cells to differ so much form each other (e.g. neurons vs muscle cells). As noted in the Wikipedia article:

> Since each cell, regardless of cell type, possesses the same genome,
>   determination of cell type must occur at the level of gene expression

[image]
I added this figure just to give a representation of the hierarchy. 
However probably you already knew this because you were asking about the mechanism of **how** these cells can become different from their parent cells. 
I will provide two important examples (again notice that this is just a simple summary):

first let's talk about **Cytoplasmic determinants**

> Cytoplasmic determinants are special molecules which play a very
>   important role during oocyte maturation, in the female's ovary ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cytoplasmic_determinant))

the cytoplasmic determinants are molecules such as mRNA or proteins which are e.g. unequally distributed in the egg cell, which means that if this cell devides one half will get other proteins(e.g. transcription factors(TF)) and mRNA than the other half. Different TFs --> different gene expression --> different proteins --> different cells. 
Secondly we have **induction** which is really important in cell differentiation:

> frequently we find that cells become different from one another as a
>   result of inductive signals coming either from other cells or from
>   their external environment ([source](http://biology.kenyon.edu/courses/biol114/Chap11/Chapter_11.html))
>   [image]

These two (induction and Cytoplasmic determinants) are important to determine the fates of cells(we also have [gastrulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastrulation), [HOX genes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hox_gene), etc). But how does the induction and the cytoplasmic determinants cause a change in gene expression? The same is true for this, there are a lot of different ways how this can happen (see [gene silencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gene_silencing#Transcriptional)):

- Genomic Imprinting
- Paramutation
- Transposon silencing (or Histone Modifications)
- Transgene silencing
- Position effect
- RNA-directed DNA methylation

I can write pages of Cellular differentiation because this question is really broad. So I will advice you to read the following articles:

- [Differential gene expression and development](http://biology.kenyon.edu/courses/biol114/Chap11/Chapter_11.html)
- [The process of differentiation](https://www.britannica.com/science/cell-biology/The-process-of-differentiation#ref962807)
- [Cellular differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_differentiation#Epigenetic_control_of_cellular_differentiation)